# SQL Query involving two different tables

Tags: sql

I need to get a result from two separate tables but I also want to use the count function.

Current query:

```
SELECT BOOK_NUM, COUNT(BOOK_NUM) 
FROM CHECKOUT 
GROUP BY BOOK_NUM        
HAVING COUNT(BOOK_NUM) > 7
```

Result:

```
BOOK_NUM    COUNT(BOOK_NUM))
----------------------------
5236            12
5235             9
```

I just also need to display the book title with this result set from the same book table.

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: coud you please elaborate a bit? it is not very clear what is wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: Mostly guessing due to lack of information in question

You will need to `JOIN` to whatever table contains the book information I'll assume this is called `BOOK` and that it has two columns `BOOK_NUM` and `NAME`. We can use the `BOOK_NUM` column on the `BOOK` table to link to the `BOOK_NUM` column in the `CHECKOUT` table, these columns do not need to have the same name. All the non aggregate columns you include in the `SELECT`, in this case `BOOK_NUM` and `BOOK.NAME` will have to be in the `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT CHECKOUT.BOOK_NUM, BOOK.NAME, COUNT(CHECKOUT.BOOK_NUM) 
FROM CHECKOUT 
JOIN BOOK ON BOOK.BOOK_NUM = CHECKOUT.BOOK_NUM
GROUP BY BOOK_NUM, BOOK.NAME      
HAVING COUNT(CHECKOUT.BOOK_NUM) >7
```

Comment: Don't forget the column alias for COUNT(CHECKOUT.BOOK_NUM).  Ex. COUNT(CHECKOUT.BOOK_NUM) AS [Totals].